# How to place a Text Box over an Image at specified location?

Tags: android, imageview, android-edittext

I want to place a TextBox over an image dynamically in java code. Here is my code:

```
    ImageView image2 = new ImageView(this);       
    image2.setPadding(25, 25, 0, 0);  
    image2.setId(2001);
    image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    image2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);  
    linear.addView(image2);
```

its my image :

[image]

how i place a textview over this image ??? help me out plz..!!!

Comment: Use Overlay, to draw and work with image/canvas

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ImageView and EditText in a RelativeLayout (wrap_content for height and width). Try first with layout Editor and get the values to set this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as demo:

```
        //Main Rel_Layout
    RelativeLayout scrollHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);
    scrollHolder.setId(++myid);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    scrollHolder.setLayoutParams(scrollHolderParams);
    scrollHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    //  Image Holder Layout
    RelativeLayout imgHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);
    imgHolder.setId(++myid);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgHolderParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imgHolder.setLayoutParams(imgHolderParams);
    imgHolder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    //imgHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    imgHolder.setLayoutParams(imgHolderParams);

        //  Image Object
    ImageView image2 = new ImageView(this);       
    image2.setId(++myid);
    image2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    //int resId = HomePage.this.getResources().getIdentifier("img2", "drawable", HomePage.this.getPackageName());
    image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    //  set image to its holder
    imgHolder.addView(image2);
    //  set imgHolder to main Layout
    scrollHolder.addView(imgHolder);
    //   set main layout as content-view
    setContentView(scrollHolder);
// this will sure help you.
```

---

OLDER
**Simplest way** is:
[1] Add EditText in your **Relative-layout**, with

layout-center-horizontal = true  and  layout-center-verticall = true

[2] In xml set its Visibility=GONE

[3] In code file take its object, and set its **"text-value"** and **Visibility = VIEW.Visible**

Comment: im donig this process dynamically not manually..!!! i wont edit in XML file... i want to do in java code

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this i java? Think you should look at `FrameLayout` and `z-index` The z-index is defined by the order the items are added:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
```